# CALayer Mask Performance

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, mask, layer

I have a UIView that has a simple mask cutout:

[image]

```
//Center Cutoff Mask - Horizontal
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let maskPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.adjusterBarView2.bounds)
maskPath.append(UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: timerLocation, y: 0, width: 8, height: 16)))
maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd

self.timelineView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

### Issue

Drawing performance seems to be weak even on a new phone, especially when screen is rotated and the view is to be re-laid out.  This is especially apparent because mask is over a video layer that re-draws constantly?

**Requisites**

- I have to stick with a mask to cut off the given area.
- Mask changes from time to time.

### Questions

1. What can I do to improve mask performance?
2. Would UIView.mask be better? Or it's the same thing under the hood?
3. Perhaps I can use something else instead of layer mask?

Comment: Can you change the grey bar drawing to simulate a mask? Have an end cap, left section, right section, endcap, and just animate the two section rectangles?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't.  There are other subview enclosed in it that does other things.  If not, I would be able to do a separate left view + right view to get away with masking I think

Comment: If it is only touch events, you can hit-test on a parent view. I was going to say a view with a transparent bg could work, but, and this is old info, every transparent layer adds to the draw time when overlapped (this is old info, and I dont know if it counts for .clearColor

Comment: Canceling touch would improve performance?

Comment: Bad speculation that the other thing the bar was doing was taking gesture input.